# Accessing the first few items in a Combobox's rowsource before the whole list has populated (populated by SQL string)

Tags: sql, performance, vba, ms-access, combobox

SO, I've looked everywhere and I'm at a loss. I'm building an access database. 
I have a form with 18 comboboxes on it. The combobox rowsources are set via vba using SQL SELECT statements (see SetSourcetbl sub below). The idea is for the user to "filter" records based on any of the fields (comboboxes) they choose. After a combobox is updated, an SQL WHERE statement is tagged onto the end of the rowsource query for each combobox on the form, so each box is updated to only display records from the predefined query (qryListAll) that meet the "filters" the user has selected so far.
 
Basically the user is using these comboboxes to build a specific SQL statement that will be used to populate a "results" form later on. 
 
Each field allows zero length strings. I've set it up so that if the "filter" (SQL statement) they've built results in one of the comboboxes having exactly one item left in its list that isn't a zero length string, the combobox is set to that item. If the query they've built results in only the zero length string (or a "single space" entry) being left in the combobox's list, the combobox turns red. 
 
My issue is that after an item has been selected in one box and all of the rowsources for the other boxes have been updated with the new SQL string, it takes a long time to check if .ListCount = 1 for each box, since the combobox has to be entirely populated before checking the .ListCount property (and each box has between ~10 and 1000 items in its list).
Is there any way (like with a recordset's .RecordCount property) to know if there is more than one item in the combobox's list without waiting for the whole list to populate? I tried setting a recordset to the same SQL string used for the rowsource of each box and using the .RecordCount property or the .Move property (to check if a second/third item exists), but it takes just as long to Set the recordset to each SQL string as it does to wait for the combobox's .ListCount to load. Here is my code. Note that SQLCriteria is a global string (bad, bad, I know) that records which "filters" have been applied thus far, and FilterCounter is a global long to see whether the SQL string needs to be prefixes with a "WHERE " or an "AND " (basically checking if the current filter is the first one that's been applied so far):

The update event of one of the comboboxes (they are all essentially the same):

```
Private Sub SelectOEMName_AfterUpdate()
    UpdateBrowseField Me.SelectOEMName
    Me!SelectFamilyName.SetFocus
    AutofillComboBoxes
End Sub
```

And the corresponding functions that are called:

```
Private Sub AutofillComboBoxes()
Dim Ctl As Control

For Each Ctl In Me.Controls
    If Ctl.ControlType = acComboBox Then
        If Ctl.ListCount = 1 Then
            If Ctl.ItemData(0) = "" Or Ctl.ItemData(0) = " " Or _
                                    IsNull(Ctl.ItemData(0)) Then
                Ctl.BackColor = REDTINT
            Else
                Ctl = Ctl.ItemData(0)
            End If
        End If
        Ctl.RowSource = ""
    End If
Next Ctl

SetSourcetbl
End Sub
```

The UpdateBrowseField sub (in a public module):

```
Public Sub UpdateBrowseField(Ctl As Control)
   Dim FieldName As String
   FieldName = Replace(Ctl.Name, "Select", "")

   If Ctl <> "" And Ctl <> " " And IsNull(Ctl) = False Then
       If FilterCounter = 0 Then
           SQLCriteria = " WHERE " & FieldName & " = '" & Ctl.Value & "'"
       Else
           SQLCriteria = SQLCriteria & " AND " & FieldName & " = '" & Ctl.Value & "'"
       End If

       SetSourcetbl
       FilterCounter = FilterCounter + 1

       Ctl.BackColor = BLUETINT
       Ctl.BackTint = 1
       If Ctl.Enabled = True Then Ctl.SetFocus
   End If
End Sub
```

The SetSourcetbl Sub (in a public module):

```
Public Sub SetSourcetbl()
   Dim CurrentForm As Form

   For Each CurrentForm In Application.Forms
       If CurrentForm.Visible And (CurrentForm.Name = "frmChooseReport" Or CurrentForm.Name = "frmBrowse") Then Exit For
   Next CurrentForm

   If CurrentForm.Name = "frmChooseReport" Or CurrentForm.Name = "frmBrowse" Then
       With CurrentForm.Controls
           !SelectOEMName.RowSource = "SELECT DISTINCT OEMName FROM (SELECT * FROM qryListAll" & SQLCriteria & ")"
           !SelectFamilyName.RowSource = "SELECT DISTINCT FamilyName FROM (SELECT * FROM qryListAll" & SQLCriteria & ")"
           !SelectModSubmod.RowSource = "SELECT DISTINCT ModSubmod FROM (SELECT * FROM qryListAll" & SQLCriteria & ")"
           !SelectFrameName.RowSource = "SELECT DISTINCT FrameName FROM (SELECT * FROM qryListAll" & SQLCriteria & ")"
        ' etc. etc. for all 18 comboboxes
       End With
   End If
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Two things to try:

1) Just use Me.ComboBox.Column(0,1) to check.

2) Use a recordset object and step forward once, then check for rst.EOF

```
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
rst.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
rst.CursorType = adOpenStatic
rst.LockType = adLockOptimistic

rst.Open "SELECT * FROM tblMyTable WHERE Condition=1"

rst.MoveNext

if rst.EOF then
'Only one row in RST
end if
```

But I think the best option would be to leave all comboboxes unbound until the immediate previous combobox is filled.

That way you are only loading one at a time. If they are sequentially dependant then you can assume that as soon as one returns 0 rows, then all subsequent comboboxes will have zero rows.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just tried .Column and it is equally slow. It seems that the combobox also has to populate before accessing values via .Column. I tried the recordset method, to no avail. Also, the comboboxes are not restricted to a sequence. The user can start in any box. E.g: a user could go to the "Model" box and select "Corolla" before having selected "Toyota" in the "Make" box. The Model box would just list all models from all car manufacturers if they did so. If they started by selecting Toyota, however, then only Toyota models would be left to choose from in the Model box.

Comment: Might be time to look at getting an MS SQL Server backend, then you can use table-valued functions, which should see significant speed gains.

Comment: Thanks JCro. Yeah, upon further investigation I think my speed limitations may be from running the actual queries to populate the comboboxes, not from the population of the comboboxes directly.